# Building a project and creating a war in different Environments using Ant

Tags: java, ant, build, web-deployment

am working on an ant build script which builds and deploys the project, and stages the code to the staging environments, ie creates a war file in the staging environments. For example the staging environments in my case are as follows: Am giving these properties in the build.properties file.

```
Env1_Deploy
Env2_Deploy
Env3_Deploy
Env4_Deploy
Env5_Deploy
PROD_DEPLOY
```

If you notice the case, all the Env..... are in mixed case where as in PROD_DEPLOY is in upper case.
The way my ant script works is when I select the build.xml-->runas-->AntScript, It prompts a dialogue box where it asks me to select the environment to build. Then I can select one among the above and then it creates the war file in the selected env.

The issue am having is when I select the **PROD_DEPLOY,** it is creating a new folder **PROD_DEPLOY_Deploy** and then creating the war files there. Below is the build.properties file and the build.xml file , any help is appreciated.

```
******build.properties file*********
deploy.folder.suffix    =_Deploy
deploy.folder.prod.suffix   =_DEPLOY

*************War Task**********************
<war destfile="${selected.env}${deploy.folder.suffix}/${project.name}.war"  needxmlfile="false">
        <fileset dir="${webroot.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>                    
        </fileset>      
        <lib dir="${temp.dir}">
        </lib>  
        <classes dir="${build.dir}"/>           
 </war>
```

Am not sure how to include the deploy.folder.prod.suffix if I want to select PROD_DEPLOY and create the war in PROD_DEPLOY